# Blow-up and Blow-down kirby local moves for non-orientable $3$-manifold

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

Can anyone explain or give a reference about the Blow-up and Blow-down Kirby local moves for non-orientable $3$-manifolds?

Thanks, advance.